# ASP.NET ModalPopupExtender appears when calling Alert JavaScript function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm facing a buggy behavior from ASP.NET Ajax Controls Toolkit ModalPopupExtender, when I call `Alert()` JavaScript function from server-side the modal appears in the back ground. I don't know why this is happens.

here is the code:

vb:

```
Sub ShowAlert(ByVal message As String)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.UpdatePanel, UpdatePanel.GetType(), "notificationScript", "<script language='JavaScript'> alert('" & message & "'); </script>", False)
End Sub
```

aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlPartialInstructions" CssClass="modal" runat="server">
         ......
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlPrintConfirmation" CssClass="modal" runat="server">
          <table class="ui-accordion">
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                      <asp:Label Text="Do you want to print the receipt?" ID="lblPrintConfirmation" runat="server"
                          meta:resourcekey="lblPrintConfirmationResource1" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="tahoma"
                          Font-Size="Large" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      <asp:Button ID="btnConfirmPrint" Text="Yes" CssClass="google-button google-button-blue"
                          runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnConfirmSaveResource1" Font-Size="Large" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <asp:Button ID="btnCancelPrint" Text="No" CssClass="google-button google-button-red"
                          runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnCancelSaveResource1" Font-Size="Large" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </asp:Panel>
      <asp:Button ID="HiddenForModel1" Text="" runat="server" CssClass="hide" CausesValidation="False" />
      <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="pnlPrintConfirmation_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
          Enabled="True" TargetControlID="HiddenForModel1" PopupControlID="pnlPrintConfirmation"
          BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" DropShadow="True" CancelControlID="btnCancelPrint"
          RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll">
      </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

      .....
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is caused by the way the `ModalPopupExtender` works. It is emitting a JavaScript which will hide the `Panel`.

Now you are registering your `alert()` call as startup script, this will hold running the `ModalPopupExtender` script as long as the user will not exit the alert windown. The simplest fix is setting `display:none` on the `Panel` so it will not need the script to hide it:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPrintConfirmation" CssClass="modal" Style="display:none;" runat="server">
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```